# split string using parameter error?

Tags: javascript

Using just the parameter fails but using a variable works, what is the difference?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Person(name) {
        //Throws error - name.reverse is not a function
        name.split("");
        name.reverse();
        name.join("");

        // Works
        var splitString = name.split("");
        var reverseString = splitString.reverse();
        var joinString = reverseString.join("");
        return joinString;
    }
    document.write(Person("Joe"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

A string cannot be reversed using name.reverse(). reverse() is a method of array. this is the solution

```
function Person(name) {
    //Throws error - name.reverse is not a function
    name = name.split("");
    name = name.reverse();
    name = name.join("");
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From MDN documentation of [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> **Return value**
>
> An array of strings split at each point where the separator occurs in the given string.

It *returns* an array, does not change the type of variable in-place... Actually, no operation I know of changes the type of variable in-place.

```
return name.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is what happens to `name` in the first three function calls. The answer is **absolutely nothing**.

```
name.split("");
name.reverse();
name.join("");
```

This says "split `name`, then discard the result, then reverse it and discard the result, then join it and discard the result". `name` never ceases to be the original string. And, crucially, `reverse` and `join` are not string functions but array functions.

Now let's look at the other calls.

```
var splitString = name.split("");
var reverseString = splitString.reverse();
var joinString = reverseString.join("");
return joinString;
```

Here you are actually *using* the results of the function calls. You are saying "split the `name` into an array of characters and call this array `splitString`, then reverse the array of characters and call it `reverseString`, then join that array together and call it `joinString`, then return `joinString`.

Note that `splitString` and `reverseString` are, technically, not strings. They  are arrays, which is why `join` and `reverse` work.

The other option, of course, is to chain it:

```
return name.split("").reverse().join("");
```